# How can I build an ios library including cocoapod dependencies with kotlin multiplaform mobile and pack all in one cocoapod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradle, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I am developing a kotlin multiplatform mobile library for iOS and Android and want to integrate some C++ library. For Android I am using JNI and with `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal` it is pretty easy to build an `AAR` file and publish it to the local maven repository. The `AAR` file does contain all binaries and a sample app that wants to use the library just has to add the `AAR` file as dependency.

For integrating the c++ lib on iOS I am using the Objective-C interop of kotlin and created some cocoapod (`pod_mycpplibrary`). In that scenario we always have to add 2 dependencies to the sample app instead of just one.

`build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
        kotlin("native.cocoapods")
...
kotlin {
  cocoapods {
        version = "1.0.0"
        summary = "mylib - a ios library"
        homepage = ""
        name = "mylib"

        ios.deploymentTarget = "13.5"

        xcodeConfigurationToNativeBuildType["CUSTOM_RELEASE"] = NativeBuildType.RELEASE

        framework {
            baseName = libName
            isStatic = true
        }

        pod("pod_mycpplibrary") {
            version = "1.0"
            headers = "foo.h"
            source = path(project.file("../pod_mycpplibrary"))

        }
    }

    val xcFramework = XCFramework(libName)
    val iosTargets = listOf(
        iosArm64(),
    )

    iosTargets.forEach {
        it.binaries{
            framework {
                baseName = libName
                xcFramework.add(this)
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
...
```

The folder structure ([inspired by this example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-with-cocoapods-sample))

- kmmproject

  - mylib

    - src
    - build.gradle.kts
  - pod_mycpplibrary

    - src
    - pod_mycpplibrary.podspec
  - ...

With `./gradlew podPublishXCFramework` I can create the cocoapod which is found in `./mylib/build/cocoapods/publish/*`

The problem is now, if I want to use the library in a iOS sample application, I always have to define both dependencies in the Podfile of the sample app:

```
target 'sample_app' do
  pod 'mylib', :path => '/path/to/kmmproject/mylib/build/cocoapods/publish/debug'
  pod 'pod_mycpplibrary', :path => '/path/to/kmmproject/mylib/pod_mycpplibrary'
end
```

Is it possible to build `mylib`in a way that I do not need to provide `pod_mycpplibrary`?

Or is there a better way to include Objective-C/C++ code into a KMM library? Maybe directly adding the code as source target (like it is possible in android) so that it is build and packed into one final cocoapod?

Comment: In my experience it's better to use C-interop and not wrap library into cocoapods, there is gradle plugin that can help - [C Klib](https://github.com/touchlab/cklib). It builds c/c++/obj-c in LLVM bitcode, and makes it easy to add cinterop. Also take a look at [this article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-extend-a-kmm-shared-module-with-cc-code) and sample [repository](https://github.com/ttypic/kmm-embedded-c). Hope it'll help